# Make program in a pipe think it has tty

Tags: shell, pipe, tty

Test environment:

```
$ mkdir testdir
$ cd testdir
$ echo | tee "file 
name"
```

Now, `ls` will print `file?name` (under Ubuntu GNU bash, at least), while `ls | cat` will print `file` and `name` in separate lines.

What I'd like to achieve is, print `file?name` with the  piped version, so something like

```
$ something ls | cat` or `ls | something | cat` or `ls | something cat
```

In other words, how to fool a command like `ls` here into thinking, it has a TTY, when it does not, in the shell?

**Note:** `ls` is just an example program here, I'm looking for generic solution, not program specific like `ls -q | cat` would be.

Comment: This is an older question than the [nominated examplar](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/8324), but as that question's answers include this question's answer, and more, I've nominated this older question for closure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to simulate a pseudo terminal (pty):

```
socat - EXEC:'ls --color=auto',pty,setsid,ctty | cat
```

There are many more option, see its [documentation](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html).

`ls` uses by default the width of the terminal for columnwise output. I found not yet a way, how to set this on a socat pty, a workaround is to use the `ls` option `-w WIDTH`.

Comment: You can do `stty rows X cols Y` inside the session to set the size of the terminal. Note that `tput lines` and `tput cols` query STDERR, while `stty` sets the state on STDIN, so make sure you pass the `stderr` option to socatas well if you want to checkthat way (this confused me at first !)

Comment: I'm constantly amazed by the power of `socat`. I don't need it often. It only seems to come up when I'm attempting the impossible, but it never disappoints.