# How does a program decide whether or not to have coloured output?

Tags: shell, terminal, process, colors

When I execute a command from a terminal that prints coloured output (such as `ls` or `gcc`), the coloured output is printed. From my understanding, the process is actually outputting [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and the terminal formats the colour.

However, if I execute the same command by another process (say a custom C application) and redirect the output to the application's own output, these colours do not persist.

How does a program decide whether or not to output text with colour format? Is there some environment variable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most such programs only output colour codes to a terminal by default; they check to see if their output is a TTY, using [`isatty(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html). There are usually options to override this behaviour: disable colours in all cases, or enable colours in all cases. For GNU `grep` for example, `--color=never` disables colours and `--color=always` enables them.

In a shell you can perform the same test using the `-t` [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) operator: `[ -t 1 ]` will succeed only if the standard output is a terminal.

Comment: Is there some way to trick the started application that the process is a tty?

Comment: Asked and answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/ already, chris13523.  Comments aren't really the place for follow-on questions, by the way.

Comment: @chris13524 see JdeBP's link; you can also force programs to output colour codes in many cases (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 18):

> *Is there some environment variable?*

Yes.  It is the `TERM` environment variable.  This is because there are several things that are used as part of the decision process.

It's difficult to generalize here, because not all programs agree on a single decision flowchart.  In fact GNU `grep`, mentioned in M. Kitt's answer, is a good example of an outlier that uses a somewhat unusual decision process with unexpected outcomes.  In very general terms, therefore:

- The standard output must be a terminal device, as determined by `isatty()`.
- The program must be able to look up the record for the terminal type in the termcap/terminfo database.
- So therefore there must *be* a terminal type to look up.  The `TERM` environment variable must exist and its value must match a database record.
- There must therefore be a terminfo/termcap database.  On some implementations of the subsystem, the location of the termcap database can be specified using a `TERMCAP` environment variable.  So on some implementations there is a *second* environment variable.
- The termcap/terminfo record must state that the terminal type supports colours.  There's a `max_colors` field in terminfo.  It's not set for terminal types that do not actually have colour capabilities.  Indeed, there's a terminfo convention that for every colourable terminal type there's another record with `-m` or `-mono` appended to the name that states no colour capability.
- The termcap/terminfo record must provide the way for the program to change colours.  There are `set_a_foreground` and `set_a_background` fields in terminfo.

It's a bit more complex than just checking `isatty()`.  It is made *further* complicated by several things:

- *Some* applications add command-line options or configuration flags that override the `isatty()` check, so that the program *always* or *never* assumes that it has a (colourable) terminal as its output.  For examples:

  - GNU `ls` has the `--color` command-line option.
  - BSD `ls` looks at the `CLICOLOR` (its absence meaning *never*) and `CLICOLOR_FORCE` (its presence meaning *always*) environment variables, and also sports the `-G` command-line option.
- *Some* applications don't use termcap/terminfo and have hardwired responses to the value of `TERM`.
- Not all terminals use ECMA-48 or ISO 8613-6 SGR sequences, which are slightly mis-named "ANSI escape sequences", for changing colours.  The termcap/terminfo mechanism is in fact designed to insulate applications from direct knowledge of the exact control sequences.  (Moreover, there's an argument to be had that *no-one* uses ISO 8613-6 SGR sequences, because *everyone agrees on the bug* of using semi-colon as the delimiter for RGB colour SGR sequences.  The standard actually specifies colon.)

As mentioned, GNU `grep` actually exhibits some of these additional complexities.  It doesn't consult termcap/terminfo, hardwires the control sequences to emit, and hardwires a response to the `TERM` environment variable.

The [Linux/Unix port of it has this code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/lib/colorize-posix.c?id=c7526623f458084cbe947f0e1b43f328481b2ca3#n36), which enables colourization only when the `TERM` environment variable exists and its value doesn't match the hardwired name `dumb`:

```
int
should_colorize (void)
{
  char const *t = getenv ("TERM");
  return t && strcmp (t, "dumb") != 0;
}
```

So even if your `TERM` is `xterm-mono`, GNU `grep` will decide to emit colours, even though other programs such as `vim` will not.

The [Win32 port of it has this code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/lib/colorize-w32.c?id=c7526623f458084cbe947f0e1b43f328481b2ca3#n52), which enables colourization either when the `TERM` environment variable *does not* exist or when it exists and its value doesn't match the hardwired name `dumb`:

```
int
should_colorize (void)
{
  char const *t = getenv ("TERM");
  return ! (t && strcmp (t, "dumb") == 0);
}
```

### GNU `grep`'s problems with colour

GNU `grep`'s colourization is actually notorious.  Because it doesn't actually do a proper job of constructing terminal output, but rather just blams in a few hardwired control sequences at various points in its output in the vain hope that that is good enough, it actually displays incorrect output in certain circumstances.

These circumstances are where it has to colourize something that is at the right hand margin of the terminal.  Programs that do terminal output properly have to account for automatic right margins.  *In addition* to the slight possibility that the terminal might not have them (viz the `auto_right_margin` field in terminfo), the behaviour of terminals that do have automatic right margins often follows the DEC VT precedent of *pending line wrap*.  GNU `grep` doesn't account for this, naïvely expecting *immediate line wrap*, and its coloured output goes wrong.

Coloured output is not a simple thing.

### Further reading

- Thomas E. Dickey (2016). "[`grep --color` does not show the right output](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#grep_colors)". *xterm FAQ*.  Invisible Island.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [*Italics and colour in manual pages on a nosh user-space virtual terminal*](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/italics-in-manuals.html).  The nosh package.

Comment: As I understand it the OP is asking about the change in behaviour when output is redirected; `$TERM` doesn't explain that. (Your answer is interesting in general, but I don't think it addresses the question...)

Comment: very interesting. I have been wanting an overview like this on how programs discover (or simply "decide") what a terminals capabilities are for a few months now.  This also gives an insight why its so hard to find an overview like this - because each program seems to do it slightly differently.

Comment: An explanation of what *pending line wrap* and *immediate line wrap* mean together with an example demonstrating the difference would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The `unbuffer` command from the **expect** package de-couples the output from the first program and the input to the second program.

You would use it like this:

```
unbuffer myshellscript.sh | grep value
```

I use it all the time with ansible and a homebrewed [ctee](https://gitlab.com/bgstack15/bgscripts/blob/master/usr/share/bgscripts/ctee.sh) script so I can see the color output on the terminal, while leaving the log file with normal (non-colorized) output.

```
unbuffer ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml | ctee /var/log/ansible/run-$( date "+%F" ).log
```