# Why grepping with color doesn't return anything?

Tags: command-line, grep, osx, bsd

I've got the following `foo.txt` file:

```
This is the first line.
This is the middle line.
This is the last line.
```

And I'm trying to grep the middle line just by the word `middle` and return the surroundings (as example), so I can highlight the whole sentence (which is especially useful when using with context option).

It **does** work without the color:

```
$ grep -o --color=none '.\+ middle .\+' foo.txt
This is the middle line.
```

But the same command **doesn't** work with color:

```
$ grep -o --color=auto '.\+ middle .\+' foo.txt
(empty line)
```

<sup>Note: Without `-o` it doesn't make any difference.</sup>

Although it works when filtering only the first half of the line:

```
$ grep -o --color=auto '.\+ middle' foo.txt
This is the middle
```

but not with the second half (`'middle .\+'`).

Why this doesn't work as expected and how can I fix it? Is it a bug or I can't use two regex expressions at the same time for some reason?

---

Tested on OS X with:

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Although it seems to work on Linux, so I'm confused.

Comment: It's working fine for me.  Does `'.\+ middle.\+'` work, without the second space?

Comment: Are you on Linux or not? With `--color=auto`? Removing second space for me doesn't work either. It happens on OSX/BSD version of grep. What's your grep version?

Comment: I'm on Linux...grep is GNU grep 2.21 though. Sorry..did not see your edit history before checking. My bad.

Comment: What you haven't told answerers is the all-important fact that your `foo.txt` has CR+LF line endings.  (-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use grep with color options it produces extra escape character sequences which tell the terminal to turn color on or off, these sequences introduce a risk of not being interpreted properly and causing unexpected results.
You can view these by capturing grep's output

#### With no color

send greps output to `output.txt`

```
% grep -o --color=none '.\+ middle .\+' foo.txt > output.txt
% cat -etv output.txt 
This is the middle line.$
```

#### With color

Forcing color with the `--color=always` option. If you redirect greps output it will - if possible - turn off color for the exact reason you have highlighted, the escape characters may produce side effects.

```
% grep -o --color=always '.\+ middle .\+' foo.txt > output.txt
% cat -etv output.txt                                             
^[[01;31m^[[KThis is the middle line.^[[m^[[K$
```

It is possible these escape sequences are causing the problem.

Comment: I just wrote http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284000/5132 , by coincidence.