# Shell - Customize the color of each line of a log file based on a pattern

Tags: text-processing, colors, syntax-highlighting

I would like to change the way I display a big (~6000 lines) log file using wim, less or whatever, in order to simplify the problem checking.

I'd like to highlight some line of the log based on a patter (i.e. `error`, `warning`, `info`...) and/or hide some others.

Which tools could I use? Do I just need a shell script? It's important that after the process, I can read the output using less, vim, ... to perform search operations!

Edit: 
a little piece of the log:

```
2016/10/25 12:19:24.403355 INFO <ServiceManager.cpp#2614 TID#3> Security object has NOT been parsed
2016/10/25 12:19:24.403369 INFO <ServiceManager.cpp#1263 TID#3> Service object sequence started
2016/10/25 12:19:24.403372 DBG <ServiceManager.cpp#1276 TID#3> preinvoke succeeded
```

Comment: `grep` has a `--color` option you could work with. `echo` can also output colored text with `-e` option, see http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting .

Comment: Also might I suggest that you [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/318755/edit) your question and add a sample of said log file, seeing the formatting will help design an accurate solution.

Comment: Thanks. How can I read the output using less, vim or another editor??

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighted-matches/981831#981831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend a shell script, based on `awk` like Valentin B. solution:

```
$ cat colorize
awk '
function color(c,s) {
        printf("\033[%dm%s\033[0m\n",30+c,s)
}
/error/ {color(1,$0);next}
/success/ {color(2,$0);next}
/warning/ {color(3,$0);next}
/INFO/ {color(4,$0);next}
/DBG/ {color(5,$0);next}
{print}
' $1
```

In order to be able to interactively view the colorized output, I would use `less` in raw mode, e.g.:

```
colorize mylog.txt | less -R
```

Comment: Yes defining a function in your `awk` script seems appropriate to avoid being redundant. Also thanks for the raw mode in `less`, that is great ! Works with my solution too by piping the output.

Comment: I didn't know that awk allows to use function like this!!! Thank you

Comment: EDIT: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighted-matches/981831#981831
What about sed command?

something like .. `sed  /INFO/s/^/<begin_color>/` and something with `/$/<end_color>. Where begin would be `\033[...` and end will be `\033[0m`.

Answer (score 6):

`awk`, as mentioned in other answers, is definitely the tool to reach for first.

But it isn't the only tool, by a long shot.

[A. L. Lambert's `logtool`](http://xjack.org./logtool/) is specifically designed for post-processing log files, and has a complex (and alas badly documented) configuration system that permits one to assign a file full of regular expressions to each one of 13 colours.

```
cat *.log | logtool
```

It has the distinction of understanding logs that have TAI64N timestamps.

To that, add:

- [`log-color-highlight`](https://npmjs.com/package/log-color-highlight)
- [`colout`](https://github.com/nojhan/colout/tree/master)
- [`ccze`](https://github.com/cornet/ccze)
- [István Karaszi's `colorize`](http://colorize.raszi.hu/)
- [Radovan Garabík's `grc`](https://github.com/garabik/grc)
- [log watcher](http://freecode.com/projects/lwatch)
- [clog](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/clog/)
- [Joakim Andersson's `colortail`](http://joakimandersson.se/projects/colortail/)
- [rainbow](https://github.com/nicoulaj/rainbow)
- [lnav](http://lnav.org/)

## problems with colourization

Alas, a few of these tools do colourization very wrongly.  They hardwire control sequences, rather than using `setaf`/`setab` and so forth from terminfo.

Also note that colourization is tricky for subtler reasons, and almost no colourization program gets it right.  To get it completely right, a colourizer has to deal with automatic margins and the DEC VT *pending line wrap* mechanism, which I have yet to see any colourizer do.  GNU `grep` has a fairly famous colourization bug in this area, but this is not a problem that is limited to `grep`.

## Further reading

- [How to have tail -f show colored output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284000/5132

Comment: apt install clog    ... nice easy config file that pipes nice.

Answer (score 1):

After checking, you can directly output colored text in the terminal using `awk`. With the example you provided you can create a awk script file (e.g. `displayLog.awk`) containing the following code:

```
# output INFO lines in cyan
$3 == "INFO" {
    print "\033[36m"$0"\033[0m"
    next
}

# don't display DBG lines
$3 == "DBG" {
    next
}

# output WARNING lines in bright yellow
$3 == "WARNING" {
    print "\033[1;33m"$0"\033[0m"
    next
}

# output ERROR lines in bright red
$3 == "ERROR" {
    print "\033[1;31m"$0"\033[0m"
    next
}

# If you want to skip all other lines, comment next line
{print}
```

Then open a clean terminal window, check the display is unlimited (you can display all 6000 lines at once) and use it this way :

```
$ awk -f displayLog.awk log.txt
```

**OR** Like user *jlliagre* suggested in his solution, pipe it to raw mode `less`:

```
$ awk -f displayLog.awk log.txt | less -R
```

That should do the trick ! You can fiddle with the colors, and what lines you want to display based on the sample `awk` code in my answer. More on color coding [here](http://www.bashguru.com/2010/01/shell-colors-colorizing-shell-scripts.html).

**EDIT**

If you want only one word to be colored instead of a whole line (for example you want ERROR to be in red only) do this:

```
$3 == "ERROR" {
    $3 = "\033[1;31m"$3"\033[0m"
    print
    next
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to  to highlight some line of the log based on a pattern (i.e. error, warning, info...) then please use the below command :

```
grep -rn "pattern" <logfile>
```

This command will display all the complete lines of the logfile which will have the pattern as mentioned above.

Comment: OP wants colored output, not just to dump line numbers, along with the matched line. Also `-r` is absolutely redundant when working on a single file.