# How to colorize some of the output of a shell-script?

Tags: shell-script, colors

I wrote a little Bash script, that uses [`spfquery`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/spfquery) for checking upon my domain email SPF record, if it passes on all providers IP addresses:

```
#!/bin/bash

# RED="\033[1;31m"
GREEN="\033[1;32m"
NOCOLOR="\033[0m"

email="[my email address]" # deleted for bots not to hound me

declare -a ips=("88.86.120.212" "88.86.120.223" "88.86.120.250" "88.86.120.213" "88.86.120.103" "46.234.104.23" "46.234.104.24")

echo -e "\n\n"

for ip in "${ips[@]}"
do
    echo -e "${GREEN}$ip${NOCOLOR}"
    spfquery -sender $email -ip $ip -helo kolbaba.stable.cz
    echo -e "\n\n"
done
```

---

Notice, there is `RED` commented out. That's because I would like the resulting message starting with any of these:

- `fail`
- `softfail`
- `neutral`
- `unknown`
- `error`
- `none`

i.e. not with:

- `pass`

to colorize in red.

But how to do this is a mystery to me?

Comment: For reference: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#foreground_text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would want to check the exit code of spfquery, then have an if/else to see if it was a pass or not. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

RED="\033[1;31m"
GREEN="\033[1;32m"
NOCOLOR="\033[0m"

email="info@vlastimilburian.cz"

declare -a ips=("88.86.120.212" "88.86.120.223" "88.86.120.250" "88.86.120.213" "88.86.120.103" "46.234.104.23" "46.234.104.24")

echo -e "\n\n"

for ip in "${ips[@]}"
do
    spfquery -sender $email -ip $ip -helo kolbaba.stable.cz

    exit_status=$?
    if [ $exit_status -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}$ip${NOCOLOR}"
    else
        echo -e "${RED}$ip${NOCOLOR}"
    fi

    echo -e "\n\n"
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure. Per the documentation you linked for [spfquery](https://linux.die.net/man/1/spfquery), a pass returns exit code 0, and each other return type returns a non-zero code (what we're checking for in the if statement).

Comment: I will contact the developer and report it as a bug. Because it returns `pass`, while return code is `2`. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Explicitly comparing `$?` to zero is a widespread antipattern.  Anything which looks like `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` is better written `if cmd; then`.  The *very purpose* of the shell's flow control statements is to run a command sequence and check its exit status to decide a conditional.

Answer (score 24):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

email="info@vlastimilburian.cz"

ips=(88.86.120.{212,223,250,213,103} 46.234.104.{23,24})

print '\n\n'

for ip ($ips) {
  spfquery -sender $email -ip $ip -helo kolbaba.stable.cz &&
    color=green || color=red

  print -P "%F{$color}$ip%f\n"
}
```

`print -P` turns on *prompt expansion* on the arguments where `%F{color}` is to set the *foreground* colour, and `%f` to reset it.

Note that the content of the variables in there (`$color` and `$ip`) are also subject to prompt expansion (something to bear in mind in cases where they may contain `%` characters (or more if the `promptsubst` option is enabled)), and without `-r`, escape sequence expansion (like `\n` above).

Other ways to access colours in `zsh`:

- the `colors` autoloadable function:

  ```
  autoload colors; colors
  echo $fg[green]text$reset_color
  ```
- the `%` parameter expansion flag, that enables prompt expansion on the content of a variable:

  ```
  var='%F{green}' reset=%f
  echo ${(%)var}text${(%)reset}
  ```

  see also:

  ```
  echo ${(%):-%F{green}}text${(%):-%f}
  ```

  or better

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "${(%):-%F{green}}$text${(%):-%f}"
  ```

  to guarantee the content of `$text` is output as-is.
- the `zsh/curses` module used to write pseudo-graphical applications in the terminal.

Comment: `${(%)reset}` seems like `%` used double times because `reset=%f` where `%` is used?

Comment: I use zsh 5.8 and do not get colored output with none of your code in a script. On terminal, it works but `echo ${(%):-green}text${(%):-%f}` and `printf '%s\n' "${(%):-green}$text${(%):-%f}"` does not print green output in termninal.

Comment: @Timo, and what does `echoti colors` output?

Comment: Regarding [echoti](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fterminfo-Module) colors I get `256` in the terminal.

Comment: @Timo, sorry my bad. Typo, code did not include the prompt escape!

Answer (score 4):

> I would like the resulting message starting with any of these […] to colorize in red.

Your question reads that you would like to colour *the output generated by the `spfquery` command*.  This is not achieved by running the command and *then* emitting colour change control sequences.  What you are achieving with the other answers is colouring just the IP addresses.  This may be what you want, but it is not what your question asks for.

The tools that you are looking for if *this* is what you really want to do are the various colourization filter utilities, such as [István Karaszi's `colorize`](http://colorize.raszi.hu/), [Radovan Garabík's `grc`](https://github.com/garabik/grc), and [Joakim Andersson's `colortail`](http://joakimandersson.se/projects/colortail/).  Configure them to recognize the appropriate things, and then pipe the output of `spfquery`, or indeed the entire `for` loop, through them.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318792/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342626/5132

Comment: Other similar tools are [colout](https://github.com/nojhan/colout) and [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/index.html).

Comment: I'll add a POSIX shell implementation by Alexey Gladkov lurking as `utils/cgrep` within http://github.com/legionus/libshell (it's designed in a pretty defensive manner) and his golang http://github.com/legionus/cfilter