# How to prevent grep --color from botching the output when a carriage return from Windows line ends is matched?

Tags: command-line, grep, newlines

I have a file with some lines likes

```
x
y
```

and when I run

```
grep -E "x$" filename.txt
```

it does not match anything. As vi shows `^M` in the end of most lines, I guess the problem is mixed Dos and Unix newlines and grep autodetecting the format.

I tried

```
grep --color=never -E "x.$" filename.txt
```

to match the extra `\r` in the end of the line and it works, but it prints a single `\r` and thus breaks when, for example, `--color=always` adds terminal control characters.

What I need is an option, to match both `\r\n$` and `\n` with `$`.

Hexdump of an example file:

```
00000000  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  
00000010  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  78 78 78 0d 0a 79 0a     |xxxxxxxxxxx..y.|
```

You can see the DOS line end and the unix line end. The output of `grep -E --color=always "x.$"` seems to be empty when `grep -E --color=never "x.$"` prints the line, probably containing the carriage return `\r` that is matched by the `.`.

Comment: Are you *certain* it doesn't match the line? You may not see the matching `x` if you have aliased grep to `grep --color=auto` for example. What does `grep -E --color=never "x.$" filename.txt` or `\grep -E "x.$" filename.txt` show?

Comment: Speculation about the contents of a file can be resolved by feeding said file to `hexdump -C`

Comment: Indeed, with `--color=never` it works. I think I get why it works (I don't get why it clears the line even when the line is very long, though). But what I really need is to have `$` match both $\n$ and `\r\n` in the same file without printing single `\r` characters.

Comment: ... see [grep --color=auto breaks when ^M is inside colored match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350352/grep-color-auto-breaks-when-m-is-inside-colored-match)

Comment: What interactive shell are you using?

Comment: @QuartzCristal bash

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU `grep`, you can use the `\s` symbol from PCRE which matches any whitespace, so `\s*` will match 0 or more whitespace characters:

```bash
$ printf 'x\r\nxx\n' > file
$ grep --color=no -P 'x\s*$' file

xx
```

Note that what looks like an empty line isn't actually empty, it's the `\r` which is causing the terminal to move back and overwrite the `x`<sup>*</sup>. You can see it in action with `od`:

```bash
$ grep -P 'x\s*$' file | od -c
0000000   x  \r  \n   x   x  \n
0000006
```

If you don't have GNU `grep`, you can use the POSIX character class `[:space:]` in the same way:

```bash
$ grep 'x[[:space:]]*$' file | od -c
0000000   x  \r  \n   x   x  \n
0000006
```

Removing the `\r` is also easy with standard tools like `tr` or `sed`:

```bash
$ tr -d '\r' < file | grep 'x$'
$ tr -d '\r' < file | grep 'x$'
x
xx
$ sed 's/\r//' file | grep 'x$'
x
xx
```

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Note that, as explained by [@dave_thompson-085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085), this only happens because I have my `grep` aliased to `grep --color=auto` which means that color codes are printed around the `x`, and that's what is causing the `x` to be overwritten as the `\r` causes the terminal to move back the cursor, so the `x` is then overwritten by the non-printing color escape codes.</sub>

Comment: Nit: CR by itself doesn't 'overwrite' or erase; your grep is set to `--color` (probably =auto) which does CSI m CSI K which erases rest of line, which following CR is all of line. Add `--color=never`, or if it's an alias just use `\grep` to get the program instead, and x happily appears. That said, I prefer the delete-CR approach, and then there's no issue.

Comment: Indeed it was, thanks @roaima.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm afraid that went over my head. You're clearly right, I just tested, but what is "CSI m CSI K"? I _think_ what you're saying is that the ANSI color escape sequences are what causes the `x` to be overwritten since `printf 'x\r\n'` doesn't hide the `x` as the newline simply changes line. Instead, here, because of the ANSI escapes, we have non-newline characters, albeit non-printing ones, and that is what is overwriting. Is that right?

Comment: CSI is [Control Sequence Introducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences). There is no overwriting, but one of the specific sequences used here -- CSI K (treated as CSI 0 K) -- does _erase_ 'from cursor to end of line' (I abbreviated as 'rest of line'). (The other sequence here is CSI m treated as CSI 0 m which in this context changes 'graphic rendition' to the terminal's default colors.)

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is an option, to match both \r\n$ and \nwith$`.

You can do it with:

```
$ grep 'x^M\?$' infile
```

To type the '^M' you should hold the `ctrl` key, press `V`, then press `ctrl` again and press `M` on the command line. A `^M` would appear, encoding a `carriage return` character.

Please understand that the output of grep will **still** contain a `carriage return`. And that that character tells the terminal to return the position for printing to the start of the line and keep printing from there. That might cause weird consequences.

What I would recommend is to clean the file with `dos2unix`.

```
dos2unix infile >clean.infile
```

Or even (just as an example, please don't cat the file, dos2unix is capable of reading it directly):

```
cat infile | dos2unix | grep 'x$'
```

Comment: dos2unix as filter may help. The question is, how grep decides when `\n` is a line end and when `\r\n` is. Using grep with dos files works fine, using it with unix files works fine as well. Files with mixed line ends are broken. I guess one can say the file is broken, still there should be a better way to handle it.

Comment: I think that `grep` works fine with either line ending. I also believe that It is what you **see** that doesn't quite feel right to you. I believe that I already answered the way to allow for an optional carriage return (use an ? after it). Is there anything else I might help you with?

Comment: My problem is, that `grep x$` prints `x` both in dos and unix files, but `x^M` for `\r\n` lines in files with mixed endings. I think a lookahead for an optional carriage return may do the correct thing.

Comment: That's your confusion, right there. The line gets printed, but then it gets hidden because the \r tells the terminal to go back to the first character and what gets printed after that removes the visibility to what was already printed. No, it is not a good idea to have \r at the end of lines, get used to that idea. @allo

Comment: What is the output you get from `GREP_COLORS=ne grep --color=always 'x^M\?$' infile` ? Remember that the `^M` needs an special type of typing.