# locate(1) buffers its output

Tags: xargs, buffer, locate

I'm using `locate(1)` from GNU findutils for a little task and it seems as if it buffers its output.  I am piping the output of locate to another task that will process the lines as locate finds them.  Since locate might take a long time to run, I thought that locate would print out the files as they were found, but it seems that locate is buffering the output.

If I run locate on a TTY, it prints out the first match immediately, and uses maybe 10 seconds to find the rest of the matches.

If, instead I run locate but pipe to cat, I see nothing until the entire command completes.

It seems that locate buffers the output, and has no way of turning it off.

What I want to achieve is to locate some files, and run a command immediately after finding it by piping the output.

```
locate something | xargs -n 1 do_something
```

But what happens is that xargs and hence do_something aren't invoked until find completes.

Comment: Since you appear to be using `find` (rather than `locate`, as suggested by your title) you should be able to use its `-exec` action to `do_something` without requiring a pipe to `xargs`

Comment: Gah, I was actually using `locate`, not `find`. Sorry about the confusion. Yes, for `find` `-exec` would be the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I found the answer immediately after posting, in a [post suggested by stackexchange when posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249737/20043).

`unbuffer` (from expect) solves this.

```
unbuffer locate something | xargs -n 1 do_something
```

runs the commands as fast as locate can find them.

Answer (score 1):

`locate` buffers the STDOUT stream, you need to make the STDOUT of `locate` unbuffered (or line buffered).

If you are on a GNU system, you can use `stdbuf` (comes with GNU `coreutils`).

To make the STDOUT of `locate` unbuffered:

```
stdbuf -o0 locate something | ...
```

Line buffered:

```
stdbuf -oL locate something | ...
```

Check `man stdbuf` to get more idea.