# Preserve systemctl colors while redirecting to a file

Tags: linux, systemd, colors

My Linux server is running [SystemD](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) (RHEL/CentOS/Debian/Ubuntu...).

I would like to redirect the output of `systemctl list-dependencies` to a file, but I want to preserve the ANSI colors (red or green according to the service status).

Unfortunately, as soon as I redirect/filter/pipe the output to a file, the color are gone:

```
systemctl list-dependencies --no-pager > /tmp/out
```

Unfortunately, `systemctl` doesn't seem to have an option like `ls --color` or `grep --color=yes`.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `script` (which is provided by the package `bsdutils` in Debian, or `util-linux` in CentOS):

```
script -q -c 'systemctl list-dependencies --no-pager' -
```

See also that question for more tricks: [How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/16640)

note: use `cat` or `less -R` to view the resulting file