# How to make any program work with the tee command?

Tags: bash, osx, stdout, tee, buffer

I wrote a program (in Ruby) and it worked well. It prints out a few lines of text and then pause for a minute and then repeats the above.

It works well (in Mac OS X's terminal), but I noted that if I wanted to keep a record of the output, by using

```
ruby myscript.rb | tee record.txt
```

then the output won't be shown on the screen, until the output reaches a certain amount, perhaps a few kb. However, this could mean 5 or 10 minutes with nothing on the screen (and nothing in the file either if I press CTRL-C).

I could modify the program to flush the output, but I thought an app should be agnostic as to what is being used with the output to STDOUT. So can `tee` be made to work well (perhaps with an option), or any other command could be used, or maybe it is an option of Bash or the Terminal app? Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

> I thought an app should be agnostic as to what is being used with the output to STDOUT.

You thought wrongly.  The runtime libraries of several programming languages, including the C and C++ languages, all share the semantics of changing the buffering according to whether they detect that the stream is attached to a terminal device.

This is a defined part of the language in many cases.  The C language standard says, for example:

> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

The usual choice if a stream is not attached to a terminal device is to select unit buffering, line buffering, or full buffering.  Unit buffering and line buffering are usual for standard error; full buffering for standard output.  But this does vary by language.

So to get the output to be not fully buffered when the output stream is a pipe in such lanugages you have to

- write your program to itself make standard output line buffered, smart buffered, or unbuffered;
- use things that hook your particular programming language's runtime library, such as the `stdbuf` command *if* your programming language is C or uses (the I/O streams part of) the C runtime library as its base (which some programming languages do not); or
- use tools such as `ptybandage` that make the program think that its standard output is a terminal, whilst taking that output and sending it to the write end of the pipe.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337109/5656721 as it's a common issue. You could use **stdbuff** or **unbuffer** for your ruby program as well.