# Why is mawk's output (STDOUT) buffered even though it is the terminal?

Tags: shell, awk, stdout, buffer

I am aware that `STDOUT` is usually buffered by commands like `mawk` (but not `gawk`), `grep`, `sed`, and so on, unless used with the appropriate options (i.e. `mawk --Winteractive`, or `grep --line-buffered`, or `sed --unbuffered`). But the buffering doesn't happen when `STDOUT` is a terminal/tty, in which case it is line buffered.

Now, what I don't get is why `STDOUT` is buffered outside of a loop send to a pipe, even though the final destination is the terminal.

A basic example :

```
$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | mawk '{print $NF}'
^C
```

Nothing happens for a long time, because `mawk` seems to be buffering it's output.

I wasn't expecting that. **`mawk`'s output is the terminal, so why is its `STDOUT` buffered ?**

Indeed, with the `-Winteractive` option the output is rendering every 3 seconds :

```
$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | mawk -Winteractive '{print $NF}'
10:57:05
10:57:08
10:57:11
^C
```

Now, this behavior is clearly `mawk` related, because it isn't reproduced if I use for example `grep`. Even without its `--line-buffered` option, `grep` doesn't buffer its `STDOUT`, which is the expected behavior given that `grep`'s `STDOUT` is the terminal :

```
$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | grep Current
Current Time is 11:01:44
Current Time is 11:01:47
Current Time is 11:01:50
^C
```

Comment: `awk` (= gawk) will show time at "3": `apt install gawk` and do `$ while sleep 3; do echo -n "Current Time is ";date +%T; done | awk '{print $NF}'` .... Info https://superuser.com/questions/75875/awk-mawk-nawk-gawk-what

Comment: I know that, `gawk` never buffers (I said it in my first paragraph). But that's beside the point, I'm trying to understand why `mawk` is buffering even when `STDOUT` is tty (terminal). Or, in other words, why my `| mawk` example behaves differently from my `| grep` example in terms of buffering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not that it's buffering its **output**.

`mawk` is the only utility that I know that buffers its **input**.

See also https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/41#issuecomment-241070898

In other words, `mawk` will not start processing its input (let alone print anything if that processing involves printing) until it has accumulated a buffer full of input.

You can verify it by running:

```
(echo 1; sleep 1; echo 2) | mawk '{system("echo "$1)}'
```

It can be disabled with the `-Winteractive` option. Note that with `-Winteractive`, records are lines regardless of the value of `RS`.

Comment: Thanks ! I scratched my head on that one... And yes, the answer is in the manpages : `-W interactive sets unbuffered writes to stdout and line buffered reads from stdin.`

Comment: Additional info : `stdbuf -i0` doesn't seem to be working with `mawk` (not that it's important, given that mawk has the `-Winteractive` option). I discovered it after digging for some more infos on `STDIN` buffering (and incidentally finding another of your answers, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411263/stdin-unbuffered#answer-411330 - it seems your are the stdio guru on this forum ;-)