# grep doesn't output until EOF if piped through cat

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

Given this minimal example

```
( echo "LINE 1" ; sleep 1 ; echo "LINE 2" ; )
```

it outputs `LINE 1` and then, after one second, outputs `LINE 2`, **as expected**.

---

If we pipe this to `grep LINE`

```
( echo "LINE 1" ; sleep 1 ; echo "LINE 2" ; ) | grep LINE
```

the behavior is the same as in the previous case, **as expected**.

---

If, alternatively, we pipe this to `cat`

```
( echo "LINE 1" ; sleep 1 ; echo "LINE 2" ; ) | cat
```

the behavior is again the same, **as expected**.

---

**However**, if we pipe to `grep LINE`, and then to `cat`,

```
( echo "LINE 1" ; sleep 1 ; echo "LINE 2" ; ) | grep LINE | cat
```

there is no output until one second passes, and both lines appear on the output immediately, which **I did not expect**.

---

Why is this happening and how can I make the last version to behave in the same way as the first three commands?

Comment: `cat` concatenates files. What are you trying to do by piping into `cat`?

Comment: @DouglasHeld When called without arguments, `cat` simply reads `stdin` and outputs into `stdout`. Of course, I came up with this question with a lot of complex stuff in place of `echo` and `cat`, but these turned out to be irrelevant, since the problem shows up with much simpler examples.

Comment: @DouglasHeld: Piping to cat is often useful to force stdout to not be a terminal. For instance, this is an easy way to get many commands to not use colorized output.

Comment: I swear this is a dupliciate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5427483/5958455) on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @wchargin thank you very much, you have taught me something new about posix that I never knew.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When (at least GNU) `grep`’s output is not a terminal, it buffers its output, which is what causes the behaviour you’re seeing. You can disable this either using GNU `grep`’s `--line-buffered` option:

```
( echo "LINE 1" ; sleep 1 ; echo "LINE 2" ; ) | grep --line-buffered LINE | cat
```

or the `stdbuf` utility:

```
( echo "LINE 1" ; sleep 1 ; echo "LINE 2" ; ) | stdbuf -oL grep LINE | cat
```

[Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/86440) has more on this topic.

Answer (score 26):

## Simplified explanation

Like many utilities, this not being something peculiar to one program, `grep` varies its standard output between being *line buffered* and *fully buffered*.  In the former case, the C library buffers output data in memory until either the buffer holding those data is filled or a linefeed character is added to it (or the program ends cleanly), whereupon it calls `write()` to actually write the buffer contents.  In the latter case, only the in-memory buffer becoming full (or the program ending cleanly) triggers the `write()`.

## More detailed explanation

This is the well-known, but slightly wrong, explanation.  In fact, standard output is not line buffered but *smart buffered* in the GNU C library and BSD C library.  Standard output is *also* flushed when reading standard *input* exhausts *its* in-memory buffer (of pre-read input) and the C library has to call `read()` to fetch some more input *and* it is reading the beginning of a new line.  (One reason for this is to prevent deadlock when another program connects itself to both ends of a filter and expects to be able to operate line-by-line, alternating between writing to the filter and reading from it; like "coprocesses" in GNU `awk` for example.)

## C library influence

`grep` and the other utilities do this — or, more strictly, the C libraries that they use do this, because this is a defined feature of programming in the C language — based upon what they detect their standard output to be.  If (and only if) it is not an interactive device, they choose full buffering, otherwise they choose smart buffering.  A pipe is considered to be not an interactive device, because the definition of being an interactive device, at least in the world of Unix and Linux, is essentially the `isatty()` call returning true for the relevant file descriptor.

## Workarounds to disable full buffering

Some utilities like `grep` have idiosyncratic options such as `--line-buffered` that change this decision, which as you can see is mis-named.  But a vanishingly small fraction of the filter programs that one could use actually have such an option.

More generally, one can use tools that dig into the specific internals of the C library and change its decision making (which have security problems if the program to be altered is set-UID, and are also specific to particular C libraries, and indeed are specific to programs written in or layered on top of the C language), or tools such as `ptybandage` that *do not* change the internals of the program but simply interpose a pseudo-terminal as standard output so that the decision comes out as "interactive", to affect this.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407472/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132

Comment: If the phrase "line buffered" is a misnomer, then it's not really the fault of `grep`, but of the underlying library calls, [`setbuf`/`setvbuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html). I don't know of a reliable online reference for the C standard, but e.g. the Linux and FreeBSD man pages along with the POSIX description of `setvbuf` call it "line buffered". Even the symbolic constant for it is `_IOLBF`.

Comment: Well now you've learned better.  This buffering strategy _is_ described in the GNU C library doco, albeit briefly.  [Laurent Bercot is more forthright on the matter.](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-tai64n.html)  [I have mentioned it too.](http://jdebp.info./Softwares/nosh/guide/tai64n.html)

Comment: I didn’t think “Your expectation is wrong” was a good heading for this excellent explanation of output buffering. I hope you don’t mind that I removed it and added some descriptive headings for each section of the answer.

Comment: @ilkkachu The C standard does indeed use "line buffered".  Per [**7.21.3 Files**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p3): "When a stream is unbuffered, ... When a stream is fully buffered, ... When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. ..."  In fact, the C Standard uses the exact phrase "line buffered" five times.  So it's not a misnomer.

Comment: Furthermore, the approach described here as "smart buffering", as I understand it,  seems to be just what the C standard describes as "line buffering".  Specifically, in addition to flushing the buffer at newlines, "When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when [...] input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment."  So this is not a GNU or BSD quirk, but rather what the language calls for.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
grep --line-buffered
```

to make grep not buffer more than one line at a time.