# What evades bash redirection?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

`Ubuntu 20`, `Bash 5`.

There is probably something silly I am overlooking! There is this C++ binary `foo`, which uses `std::cout`, `printf()`and `puts()` to do its logging.

When I run it as `./foo` from the terminal, I get some output (and a segmentation fault).

When I redirect everything `./foo > log`, I get only a part of the output. When I spread that `./foo 1>one 2>two` then `one`, as expected, contains the shortened output and `two` contains nothing.

There is (obviously) no central logging facility, so I can't imagine how to force flushing.

What could be wrong?

---

```
$./foo
text1
text2
```

---

```
$./foo > log ; cat log
text1
```

Comment: It's unclear _what_ part of the output you are referring to.

Comment: Maybe the binary is detecting that its output is being redirected and changes what it prints. Various tools do that, for instance `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Logging has nothing to do with it, and this is a basic facet of C and C++ programming that you need to learn.

The standard I/O library routines are fully buffering output, because the runtime library has determined that standard output is not a terminal device.  If you want standard output line buffered, you turn line buffering on in code with `setvbuf()`, or you persuade the C runtime library that standard output is a terminal with tools like Bernstein `ptybandage`, or you use idiosyncratics hooks into the C library to turn on line buffering with code injection tools such as `stdbuff`.  `ptybandage` is probably the best choice here.  It is non-invasive and you probably do *not* want to have explicit buffering overrides in your program, once you actually understand the nature of standard I/O buffering.

Do not log to standard output, by the way.  Log to `std::clog`.

## Further reading

- Toolsets: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132
- Semantics: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467061/5132

Comment: can you expand a bit on what buffering has to do with it?

Comment: ... I mean that it looks like they only viewed the output file after the program completed, so the buffers should be flushed by then, and there shouldn't be the same effect of delayed output as with, e.g. `tail -f |grep`. And if all the output goes to stdout, there's only one fd and one file position involved, so even if `stdio` and `iostream` buffer independently, they shouldn't overwrite each other, right? What am I missing?

Comment: @ilkkachu the program terminates with a segmentation fault. The program is launched the same way, just with redirection one time. Is writing to a file different than to `stdout`? I would prefer not to change the source code and it's chaotic logging.

Comment: @Vorac, right, if it terminates with a segmentation fault every time, then some output might be left in the buffers and not written. Maybe that's what JdeBP referred to here, not that their answer was too clear on that. Your snippets about the output in the question also don't show the segmentation fault.