# Why can't I do two greps after a tail?

Tags: grep, pipe, tail

I'm able to run this command successfully:

```
tail -f my_file.txt | grep foo
```

It shows only the lines with the string `foo`, and it keeps showing them.

But when I run this command:

```
tail -f my_file.txt | grep foo | grep bar
```

It doesn't show any lines, even though there are lines that include both `foo` and `bar`.

I know there is a solution for using multiple patterns in a single `grep` call, but I want to know why this line failed.

Comment: I guess doing `cat my_file.txt | grep foo | grep bar` **will** show the correct output for the  contents of `my_file.txt` present when executing `cat`, right? The issue is only for the new lines written to `my_file.txt` while the command is running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep doesn't output until EOF if piped through cat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467039/grep-doesnt-output-until-eof-if-piped-through-cat)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's because the default behaviour of the C runtime library is to buffer writes to stdout until a full block of data is written (some kilobytes, usually), unless stdout is connected to a terminal.

You'll get output once the middle grep has printed a full block, but then you have to wait again for the next block to fill, and so on. It's an optimization for throughput, and works much better when the left-hand command just does some task and terminates, instead of waiting for something.

GNU grep has the `--line-buffered` option to turn off that buffering, so this should work better:

```
tail -f my_file.txt | grep --line-buffered foo | grep bar
```

The last `grep` prints to the terminal so it's line buffered by default and doesn't need an option.

See  [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/170373) for generic solutions to the buffering issue.

---

In this particular case of two greps, you could use e.g. a single AWK instead as Stéphane Chazelas mentioned in a comment:

```
tail -f my_file.txt | awk '/foo/ && /bar/'
```

(Incidentally, you could also do things like `awk '/foo/ && !/bar/'`, catching lines with `foo` but no `bar`.)

Doing the same in grep would be harder, as `grep -e foo -e bar` matches any lines that contain *either* `foo` *or* `bar`. You'd need something like

```
... | grep -E -e 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'
```

instead.

Answer (score -2):

From a boolean point of views it seems you're expecting **foo *OR* bar** with your grep, yet from the way you did you should expect **foo *AND* bar** -- The only lines that will ever be grepped for **bar** are those that passed the **foo** grep in the first place.

If you want either foo/bar popping up on stdout you need to use:

> tail -f my_file.txt | grep "foo|bar"

You can add as many keywords "pretty|much|like|these", just don't forget the quotes. (Or use *multiple\|unquoted\|terms*)

On a second note: Since it's a *tail -f* (follow) it might also happen for your_file.txt to not be appended with a line containing both keywords at that very specific time, it's usually best to cut a share of that file that is known to have what you expect:

> tail -n 500 my_file.txt > my_sample.txt

From there you can try whatever grep you feel like with a known text. (I'm guessing the last 500 lines is enough, adjust as needed.)

Comment: For `foo` OR `bar`, that's either `grep -e foo -e bar` or `grep -E 'foo|bar'`. Basic regexps (without -E) don't have an alternation operator though some grep support it as a `\|` extension.

Comment: The OP make it very clear that they want *lines that include both foo and bar*, so they want  AND, not OR.

Comment: `tail -f file` prints the last 10 lines that were initially in the file and waits and prints all the additional lines that come thereafter. To print all the initial lines and all following, use `tail -n +1 -f file`.