# less: advertise terminfo through pipe

Tags: pty, pager, terminfo

If I do `ls | less`, `ls` detects that it isn't connected to a terminal, which is fair enough. Except that `less` *is* connected to a terminal. In this setup, `ls` could produce the coloured and columnised output targetting terminals, and `less` could deal with it properly. You can get colours working properly with `ls --color=force | less -r`, but that's more typing, and it doesn't do columns.

What would be cool is if there were a switch on `less` that tells whatever is hooked up to it to treat it like a real terminal. So you could do `ls | less -T` and get the coloured and columnised listing in `less`.

1. Has anything like this been done?
2. Could `less` or a pager like it actually do that by itself, or would this require cooperation from the shell? For instance, would the shell need to set up a pseudoterminal for `ls` to connect to?

Answer (score 7):

It's the shell that sets the pipeline up. `less` is not involved in that.

When you do `ls | less`, the shell starts `ls` and `less` concurrently after having made the stdout of the process that will eventually execute `ls` the writing end of a pipe and the stdin of the one that will execute `less` the reading end of that same pipe.

`ls` detects that its stdout is not a tty device, and alters its behaviour accordingly. There's nothing that `less` can do about it.

What the *shell* could do is use a pseudo-terminal pair instead of a pipe to connect the two processes, but that would be a bad idea, as pseudo-terminals were not designed for that. For one, the tearing down of the connection would be problematic. `less` would probably be confused if its stdin was a pseudo-terminal master.

Another approach would be to get a 3rd process that reads the output of `ls` via a pseudo-terminal pair and feeds it to `less` via a pipe like with [@JdeBP's `ptyrun` or `ptybandage`](/a/521058), or `expect`'s `unbuffer` or using `zsh`'s `zpty` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/zpty
ttypager() { (zpty c "stty raw -echo; ${(q)@}"; zpty -r c) | less -RFX; }

ttypager ls
```

`ls` would run in a new session in a new terminal, so would not receive SIGINT when you press ^C, or SIGPIPE when you quit `less` before it finishes writing. However, since the process holding the master side (a subshell here) would still in those cases, `ls` would receive a SIGHUP and die nonetheless.

`zpty` here runs the command as if using `eval`, so aliases are going to be expanded. Actually, they would be expanded even if you called `ttypager \ls` as `ttypager` would still receive `ls` as argument and perform the alias expansion later.

Also note that both stdout and stderr would go to that pseudo-terminal and eventually to the pipe.

That's still a bit of a dirty hack. Here, the simplest would be to  tell `ls` to behave as if it was connected to a terminal.

You could use a helper function like:

```
paged_ls() { ls -C --color=always "$@" | less -RFX; }
```

Where `-C` forces the output in column (which some implementations including GNU `ls` do by default when the output goes to a terminal) and `--color=always` force the output in colour regardless of whether the output goes to a terminal or not.

Answer (score 3):

The general way to do this is with tools such as Bernstein's `ptybandage`:

```
$ ptybandage ls > wibble ; less wibble
```

Or, better in this case, Bernstein's `ptyrun`:

```
$ ptyrun ls | less
```

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptyrun`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptyrun.xml). *djbwares*.
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptybandage`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptybandage.xml). *djbwares*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`ptyrun`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ptyrun.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`ptybandage`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ptybandage.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.