# less -R (-r) doesn't produce colored output

Tags: terminal, colors, less

I'm trying to get colored less output in my terminal. Below is how I expect the output to look, and underneath that what "less -r" *or* "less -R" actually produces.

[image]

[image]

I'm using a build of suckless st that's collected here:

https://github.com/Lukesmithxyz/st

And I haven't really customized it at all.

I should also mention that every other terminal I've tried (including TTY2) has the same behavior.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to force `ls` to use colours, otherwise it disables them when not writing to a terminal:

```
ls -l --color | less -R
```

You can also use `unbuffer` (part of `expect`):

```
unbuffer ls -l | less -R
```

See [How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/86440) for more information on the latter approach.