# script -c '...' does NOT print colors

Tags: linux, tty, colors, pty

**edit**: I was in EternalTerminal session, and that was the source of the difference. In a regular `ssh`, it works.

I need to get commands in a pipe to believe they are in a PTY and emit colorized output.

`script -c` [is known to be a workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249726/54895) to do so.

But for me, `ls --color=auto` is colorized, and in `script -q -e -c 'ls --color=auto' log; cat log` nothing is colorized.

I do have `LS_COLORS` set.

The same happens with `gcc`: it's colorized in an interactive shell, but not in `script -c`.

How do programs in `script -c` find out that they are not in a tty? Why did it work before and doesn't now?

```
$ script -V
script from util-linux 2.33.2
$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.31
```

Comment: `ls` doesn't apply colours by default, IIRC. Is your `ls` an alias to `ls --color`?

Comment: Right, thanks. It's `ls --color=auto`. Updating the question. BTW, I'm also in `ssh`.

Comment: I can't repro - `script -q -e -c 'ls --color' /tmp/log` shows colours (SSH to a Arch Linux system from a macOS iTerm): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFyJX.jpg

Comment: Yep. I also find that `script -q -e -c 'ls --color' /tmp/log` gives colours on Cygwin, Raspbian 10, Debian 10, and CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

After describing my environment in more detail, I found that the suspect that makes the difference is Eternal Terminal.

I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/MisterTea/EternalTerminal/issues/321), in case if it's a problem and not an intended behavior.